# Linux - команда History

Tags: unix, linux

Как можно сохранить всё что было введено в командную строку (history) в какой-нибудь файл в ос линукс? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию bash хранит историю в ~/.bash_history. Но если это какая-то самописная оболочка, то при получении каких-то данных просто записывать все n параметров в файл (argv[0]...argv[n-1])

Comment: в какой папке этот файл? :)

Comment: ~ означает домашняя папка пользователя, т.е. /home/user_name, где user_name имя Вашего пользователя

Comment: ага. спасибо. папка /root/ всё-таки. При перезагрузке ос история удаляется? Я не нашел ничего за прошлый год))

Answer (score 4):

Команда history без параметров выдает список всех сохраненных в истории команд. Поэтому можно сделать так:

> history > file_name

Или открыть файл ~/.bash_history, где история и хранится

> При перезагрузке ос история удаляется?

По умолчанию - нет, не удаляется

> Я не нашел ничего за прошлый год

Кол-во сохраняемых команд настраивается, но обычно это несколько сотен.